# Select all rows from table having two given values anywhere in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table of bus route. this table has fields like bus no. , route code , starting point , end point, and upto 10 halts from halt1 , halt2...halt10 . i have filled data in this table. now i want to select all rows having two values,for example jaipur and vasai. in my table, there are two rows that have jaipur and vasai. In one row, jaipur is in column halt2 and vasai in halt9. Similarly another row has jaipur in halt4 column and vasai in halt10 column.
please help me to find out sql query. I am using MS SQL server.
scrip

```
    USE [JaipuBus]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MyRoutes]    Script Date: 02/24/2014 13:28:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyRoutes](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Route_No] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Route_Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Color] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Start_Point] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [End_Point] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [halt1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [halt2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [halt3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [halt4] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [halt5] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [halt6] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [halt7] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [halt8] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [halt9] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [halt10] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyRoutes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

[image]

Comment: What if you need to add one more bus stop - in this case you have to add one more COLUMN in your table (`halt11`)? Try to normalize you DB structure and then a query you need will be simple...

Comment: Can you post the table structure?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyRoutes](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Route_No] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Route_Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Color] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Start_Point] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [End_Point] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [halt1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [halt2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [halt3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [halt4] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [halt5] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [halt6] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [halt7] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [halt8] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [halt9] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [halt10] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
yes valex is right. there may be 50 halts between two station

Comment: Then you should go for Normalization. Please put the schema to the question section and not in the comment.

Comment: i don't have min. 10 reputation otherwise i could post image of table.please vote so that i can upload image.

Comment: You are now at 11, paste it

Comment: thanks every one. i have updated question with code and image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `CONTAINS`

```
SELECT *
WHERE CONTAINS((startingpoint,endpoint,halt1,halt2,halt3,halt4,halt5,halt6,halt7,halt8,halt9,halt10), 'jaipur')
   AND CONTAINS((startingpoint,endpoint,halt1,halt2,halt3,halt4,halt5,halt6,halt7,halt8,halt9,halt10), 'vasai');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM bus_rout WHERE (halt1='aaa' OR halt2='aaa' OR .... halt10='aaa') AND (halt1='bbb' OR halt2='bbb' OR ....... halt10='bbb')
```

The where clause could be generated by code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input, it seems to be a necessity for you to have Normalized table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyRoutes]( 
  [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
  [Route_No] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
  [Route_Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
  [Color] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
  [Start_Point] [nvarchar](200) NULL, 
  [End_Point] [nvarchar](200) NULL, 
  [HaltNum] INT, 
  [Halt] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

Then a query to solve the routes problem can be written as below:

```
SELECT a.Route_No, a.Route_Code, a.Color, a.Start_Point, a.End_Point,
a.HaltNum StartNum, b.HaltNum StopNum
FROM MyRoutes a
INNER JOIN MyRoutes b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.Halt = 'jaipur' AND b.Halt = 'vasai'
AND a.HaltNum < b.HaltNum
```

Even better design of the table structure would be to have a separate master table for all Stops where you can maintain only `StopId` and `StopName`. In the `MyRoutes` table then you can have HaltId as foreign key referencing `StopId` column of the all stops master table. The above query would then need to inner join with this table twice to have conditions on `StopName`